# JavaFX WebView Opening Older Versions of Websites

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I'm working on a JavaFX browser app and I noticed that lots of the pages that I open in my WebView are much older versions of the page than they should be.

For example, Google in a regular browser like Chrome looks like this.

[image]

And then in my WebView, the same website is displayed like this.

[image]

It obviously doesn't affect any performance or anything however it makes everything feel much clunkier and like I'm using the Internet back in 2000. Is there any way to use a nicer version of the websites or is this an issue with WebViews that I'm stuck with?

Comment: If you modify the [user agent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#userAgentProperty) enough to mimic browsers like Chrome or Firefox you get the web page shown in the first image. I've written this as a comment to another question before, but I hesitate to make it an answer because I'm unsure of the legitimacy of this solution (I'm not comfortable with web technologies).

Comment: @Slaw could this be a javascript issue

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think it's simply Google delivering a different page depending on the user agent. It may think that the default user agent is not capable of displaying the modern look, so it sends a not-so-modern look. Looking at the default user agent, it contains something like `Safari/605.1`. Maybe it's a Safari issue (see [this old thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6511273?page=1)). Whatever the case, I find simply appending something like `Firefox/62.0` to the user agent gives me the modern Google look.